# How to show if $A \subset V \subset X$ and $V$ deformation retracts onto $A$, then $H_{n}(X,A) \simeq H_{n}(X,V)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

How can I show that if $A \subset V \subset X$ and $V$ deformation retracts onto $A$, then $H_{n}(X,A) \simeq H_{n}(X,V)$?

I am trying to use the fact that if a map of pairs $f:(X,A)\rightarrow (Y,B)$ has the property that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and the restriction $f:A \rightarrow B$ are both homotopy equivalence then the induced map $f_{*}:H_{n}(X,A)\rightarrow H_{n}(Y,B)$ is an isomorphism but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the long exact homology sequence of the triple  $(X,V,A)$
this follows as long as $H_*(V,A)=0$. But as $A$ is a deformation
retract of $V$, the inclusion $A\to V$ is a homotopy equivalence.
So $H_*(A)\to H_*(V)$ is an isomorphism, and so $H_*(V,A)=0$
by the long exact sequence of homology.

Comment: Is there a way to show it directly?

Comment: @TuoTuo Depends on what "directly" means. An alternative way to do it is to write down the commutative diagram with top row the homology LES for $(X, A)$ and bottom row the homology LES for $(X, V)$, and use a similar argument as Lord Shark to conclude $H_*(X, A) \to H_*(X, V)$ is an isomorphism. But this is less direct than what the existing answer says...